# PHP .htaccess rewrite url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, php-7.2

I have written below URL rewrite rule but it is removing post parameter too. Kindly help me to rewrite URL with original paramter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why do you redirect requests? Possible, it works if you remove `R=301`

Comment: do you really mean `POST` parameters?? I doubt that they get lost. I guess you mean the query string (of a GET request)

Comment: @Jeff I have HTML form which is sending post parameter, when I send with .php it works but when I send without php all parameter goes away

Comment: Removing R=301 works @NicoHaase Please post your answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the flag `R=301`, you're performing a redirect instead of only rewriting the URL internally. Remove that and everything should work fine